# mdb (MS Access DB) with iOS

Tags: iphone, ms-access

I'm developing an app that should be able to get some data from an mdb (access database). I don't need to do queries or so, just get info in the db in a human readable format.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Max

Answer (score -1):

You need to use SQLite. MSAccess Database is not supported. Use FMDB for your SQLite purpose.

Comment: my app uses sqlite3 but I have to import mdb contents into my sqlite. I'm considering, if possible, to develop e java class to convert the mdb into xml and then parse the xml, but it's very complicated to me.